# Partial Correlation and Partial (Linear) Regression

Tags: linear-model, partial-correlation

Consider the linear regression model $$\boldsymbol y = \alpha + \beta \boldsymbol x + \gamma \boldsymbol z + \boldsymbol u,$$ and denote the OLSE of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ by $\hat\alpha$, $\hat\beta$ and $\hat\gamma$, respectively. The Frisch-Waugh-Lovell Theorem tells us that we can obtain the OLSE of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by 'netting out' $\boldsymbol z$, i.e., the OLSE of $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ equal the OLSE of $\nu$ and $\delta$, respectively, in the regression $$\boldsymbol P\boldsymbol y = \nu + \delta\boldsymbol P\boldsymbol x + \boldsymbol P\boldsymbol u,$$ where $\boldsymbol P := \boldsymbol I - \boldsymbol z(\boldsymbol z'\boldsymbol z)^{-1}\boldsymbol z'$.

So I thought that the partial correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$ (after 'netting out' $Z$) is given by $$\hat\delta\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}(\boldsymbol P\boldsymbol x)}{\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}(\boldsymbol P\boldsymbol y)}}.$$ However, this does not seem to be the case. According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation), the partial correlation coefficient is obtained by first regressing $X$ on $Z$ and then compute the residuals $\boldsymbol e_{XZ}$. Next, $Y$ is regressed on $Z$ and the residuals $\boldsymbol e_{YZ}$ are computed. The partial regression coefficient is then given by $$\frac{\langle \boldsymbol e_{YZ}, \boldsymbol e_{XZ}\rangle}{\Vert\boldsymbol e_{YZ}\Vert\cdot\Vert\boldsymbol e_{XZ}\Vert},$$ where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the usual Euclidean inner product and $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ the associated norm.

**Question:** Are the two definitions of partial correlation presented here are related in some sense? If yes, how?

Both definitions starts with the same idea: regress $X$ on $Z$ and obtain the residuals. However, in the second step, the Frisch-Waugh-Lovell approach regresses $Y$ on the residuals obtained in the first step, while the other approach regresses $Y$ on $Z$ and then computes the correlation from the residuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake when defining your $M$ matrix. I will show that both partial correlations agree if you consider a different $M$.

Let $$X := \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_1 \\ 1 & x_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_n \end{pmatrix}, y := \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix},\qquad\text{and}\qquad z := \begin{pmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \\ \vdots \\ z_n \end{pmatrix}.$$ Then \begin{align*} e_{YX} &= y  - X\hat\xi \\ e_{ZX} &= z - X\hat\phi \end{align*}
with $\hat\xi$ and $\hat\phi$ being the OLS estimator when regressing $y$ respective $z$ on $X$. Note that \begin{align*} \hat\xi &= (X'X)^{-1}(X'y) \\ \hat\phi &= (X'X)^{-1}(X'z). \end{align*} Hence $e_{YX} = My$ and $e_{ZX} = Mz$, where $M = I - X(X'X)^{-1}X'$. Note how my $M$ is different from yours. Now observe that $$\operatorname{Cor}(e_{YX},e_{ZX}) := \frac{\langle e_{YX}, e_{ZX}\rangle}{\Vert e_{YX}\Vert\cdot\Vert e_{ZX}\Vert} = \hat b\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}(e_{ZX})}{\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}(e_{YX})}} = \hat b\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}(Mz)}{\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}(My)}},$$ where $\hat b$ is the OLS estimator when regressing $e_{YX}$ on $e_{ZX}$ (without constant).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Indeed, you are right, I made a mistake. However, I suppose that there is a typo in your answer. It should read $e_{YX}$ and $e_{ZX}$ (instead of $y$ and $z$, respectively).

Comment: Indeed, that was a mistake.